# Script + template to generate static web site?

Tags: cms, static-content

After giving it more thought, I don't actually need a PHP-based CMS for a small, static web site.

Does someone know of a good solution that can run on Windows that would take basic HTML pages and JPG pictures, combine those with a template, and generate a static site ready to be FTPed to an web server?

Thank you.

---

Edit: For those looking for the same information, here's some well-known tools to create a static site:

- http://get-simple.info/
- http://gpeasy.com/How_Easy
- http://textpattern.com/features
- http://nanoc.stoneship.org/
- http://www.movabletype.com/

Answer (score 1):

The [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/) is a mature product that is free and runs on Windows. It's written in Perl and says you don't need to know Perl to use it. However you do need to know a bit about installing Perl.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That's what I had in mind. Ideally, users would just create raw HTML files (ie. only basic formatting allowed) using their favorite HTML WYSIWYG editor, and the CMS would take the BODY part and use a template to generate a final page.

Answer (score 0):

[Stacey](http://staceyapp.com/) is a static content management system powered by files and folders alone (no backend, no database). It requires PHP 5+. (Designed to run on a server, but could be used on a Windows box.)

[Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) is a static CMS for Ruby that also runs on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you use node.js, try http://assemble.io. It's 100% open source and JavaScript, and it runs on Grunt (grunt.js).