# Updating Old Site To New. Which Content Management System Lets Me Retain My Old URL?

Tags: web-development, url, cms, design

My old site is done in HTML with .html as file extension. 
To allow all those users who visit sites by typing a specific page url, and URL structure being good, I do not retain every single old url as possible including index.html as the main entry page even the content management system might start with index.php or anything like that.

Could you tell me which content management system lets me pick my own url for each page or entry ?

Example :
given url 1 by Content Management System as travel/whereonearth.php
my old url : travel/whereonearthe.html
given url 2 : travel/mars.php
my old url 2 : travel/mar.html
i will type all old url for each entry page, once the site up, i will delete the old .html pages. This is for users and not for seo or anything like. I don't like .htaccess or anything like that so please list the CMS that allows me to do this.

Comment: "I don't like .htaccess or anything like that so please list the CMS that allows me to do this." -- You may want to learn to like .htaccess and things like that as it gives you far more flexibility in CMS choice

Answer (score 0):

There are CMS systems (such as [Movable Type](http://www.movabletype.org/)) that will output plain .html pages or, at worst, ([LightNEasy](http://www.lightneasy.org/)) .php pages and if you Googled you would have found some [resources](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15291/script-template-to-generate-static-web-site) here as well.  They are out there but the devil is in the details and this may get closed as Not Constructive.